# Extract external javascript query string/anchor value: file.js#foo=bar

Tags: javascript, query-string, cross-domain, anchor, extract

http://mycloud.net/js/file.js#foo=bar

I'm trying to load a cross domain javascript file, and want to pass a variable along on the query string. I have seen the above '#' method used, but am unsure of how to extract the 'foo' value from within the file.js. Any clues how to handle this without the aid of server side help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is actually a way to get the *current* `script`, e.g.:

```
// external script
(function () {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
      currentScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1],
      scriptUrl = currentScript;

  alert("scriptUrl: " + scriptUrl);
})();
```

The above works because at the moment when the `script` element is being executed, is the last `script` element of the DOM (`scripts[scripts.length - 1]`).

Then you have only to make string manipulation on your `scriptUrl` to extract the GET parameters.

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ifoco3/), and the external script is [here](http://jsbin.com/ewobe/2/edit).

Answer (score 1):

The only way for the script to get hold of the value in the bookmark, would be to somehow find it's `script` tag in the document and extract it from the `scr` attribute.

The bookmark part of the URL isn't sent along in the request, so you can't pick it up using server side code either.